# Two simultaneous RotationTransitions on the same node

Tags: java, animation, javafx-2

I've been playing with animations while getting acquainted with JavaFX 2.0, and I wrote a small test program that was intended to rotate a rectangle along its X and Y axes. Here is the test program:

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.ParallelTransition;
import javafx.animation.RotateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.RectangleBuilder;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ParallelTransitionTest extends Application
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        launch( args );
    }

    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage ) throws Exception
    {
        init( primaryStage );
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void init( Stage primaryStage )
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle( "Parallel Transition" );
        primaryStage.setResizable( true );

        // Create the scene
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene( root, 800, 600, true );
        scene.setFill( Color.BLACK );
        primaryStage.setScene( scene );

        Rectangle rect = RectangleBuilder.create()
                .width( 100 ).height( 100 )
                .x( 350 ).y( 250 )
                .fill( Color.BLUE )
                .build();

        RotateTransition rotationY = new RotateTransition();
        rotationY.setAxis( Rotate.Y_AXIS );
        rotationY.setDuration( Duration.seconds( 5 ) );
        rotationY.setByAngle( 360 );
        rotationY.setNode( rect );
        rotationY.setAutoReverse( true );
        rotationY.setCycleCount( Animation.INDEFINITE );

        RotateTransition rotationX = new RotateTransition();
        rotationX.setAxis( Rotate.X_AXIS );
        rotationX.setDuration( Duration.seconds( 5 ) );
        rotationX.setByAngle( 360 );
        rotationX.setNode( rect );
        rotationX.setAutoReverse( true );
        rotationX.setCycleCount( Animation.INDEFINITE );

        FadeTransition fade = new FadeTransition();
        fade.setDuration( Duration.seconds( 5 ) );
        fade.setToValue( 0.2 );
        fade.setNode( rect );
        fade.setAutoReverse( true );
        fade.setCycleCount( Animation.INDEFINITE );

        ParallelTransition transition = new ParallelTransition( rect,
                rotationX, rotationY, fade );
        transition.setAutoReverse( true );
        transition.play();

        root.getChildren().add( rect );
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the rotation is only happening for one of the axes. My assumption is that both `RotationTransition`s are running, but that one is overwriting the rotation applied by the other. Is this the intended behavior of `RotationTransition`?

Also, if the following three lines are commented:

```
        rotationY.setNode( rect );
        ...
        rotationX.setNode( rect );
        ...
        fade.setNode( rect );
```

I get a `NullPointerException`. The docs suggest that you shouldn't need to set the nodes on transitions included in a `ParallelTransition`. Is this a bug?

Comment: Try [setting](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#setCamera%28javafx.scene.Camera%29) a [PerspectiveCamera](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/PerspectiveCamera.html) on the scene.

Comment: @jewelsea Using a `PerspectiveCamera` changed the perspective (as expected), but did not fix the simultaneous `RotationTransition` issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should create another node add your rect to that node, and then:

```
RotateTransition rotationY = new RotateTransition();
        rotationY.setAxis( Rotate.Y_AXIS );
        rotationY.setDuration( Duration.seconds( 5 ) );
        rotationY.setByAngle( 360 );
        rotationY.setNode( rect );
        rotationY.setAutoReverse( true );
        rotationY.setCycleCount( Animation.INDEFINITE );

        RotateTransition rotationX = new RotateTransition();
        rotationX.setAxis( Rotate.X_AXIS );
        rotationX.setDuration( Duration.seconds( 5 ) );
        rotationX.setByAngle( 360 );
        rotationX.setNode( NEWNODE );
        rotationX.setAutoReverse( true );
        rotationX.setCycleCount( Animation.INDEFINITE );
```

Comment: +1 because the modification you give is simple and I would bet that it works. However, my question is less about getting the example to work (there are lots of ways to achieve this same goal) and more about the reason for the behavior exhibited by my code. I haven't looked at the docs recently so they may have been updated since I read them, but at the time I saw no reason why my code should not work. Still hoping that someone (maybe even you) knows why. Btw, sorry it took me so long to respond to your answer.